# node-webkit destroys print on Windows

Tags: javascript, node.js, printing, chromium, node-webkit

When printing within a node-webkit App the result isn't as expected. It seems that the characters are rotated and cutted. Here is an example with a simple Lorem Ipsum text block:

[image: Lorem ipsum on node-webkit]

I use the standard JS-print-command:

```
window.print();
```

It's the same printer and App that prints on OSX correctly, but "crashes" on Windows, as seen above.